# StringProperty, None vs. Empty String

Tags: google-app-engine, string

```
class Person(db.Model):
  first_name=db.StringProperty()
  middle_name=db.StringProperty()
  last_name=db.StringProperty()

p1=Person(first_name='john',                 last_name='smith')
p2=Person(first_name='john',middle_name=None,last_name='smith')
p3=Person(first_name='john',middle_name='',  last_name='smith')
```

p1 and p2 is the same with middle_name = None

p3 has middle_name = empty string

Which is better to work with?

In SQL, I tend to set columns to not null default ''

Comment: At this point, I am thinking it's better to work with just empty string and not both None and empty string. Which in SQL is equivalent to NOT NULL default ""

Answer (score 2):

They're completely different.  One (None) is equivalent to SQL NULL.  This can mean they don't have a middle name or you don't know it.  '' means they do have a middle name, of length 0.  This is almost never the case.

Comment: I know what you mean, but an empty string is exactly what I'll get if the form field is left unfilled. middle_name=cgi.escape(self.request.get('middle_name'))

Comment: Then you need to explicitly map from HTML form data -> database data.